# Jquery hover menu show hide

Tags: jquery, hoverintent

I have a Wordpress menu with jquery hoverIntent with following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".menu-item").hoverIntent({
        over: function(){
            $(this).children('ul').fadeIn(200);
        $('.current_page_item, .current_page_ancestor, .current_page_parent').children('ul').hide();

    },
    out: function(){            
        $(this).children('ul').fadeOut(200); 
        $('.current_page_item, .current_page_ancestor, .current_page_parent').children('ul').show();
    },
    timeout: 200
});
```

I have shown by default (CSS) the active submenus (the ones from the current page or parent page) and have to hide them , when the user hovers over a non-active menu item (because of overlapping). On mouseout the submenu from the active page should come back visibile.

Everything is working, except the submenu of the active menu (the one shown by default) which is flickering on mouse over. I have tried to exclude these classes using not() and anything else, but I am really stuck now.

Thank you!

Comment: can you make a demo on http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: sure: http://jsfiddle.net/ibloom/krstv/1/